# printk implementation in linux

Tags: linux, unix, printk

I want to know how printk passes the data from the kernel space to the user space. I have heard of relayfs, which provides that the efficient and unified file-system to transfer huge data from the kernel space to user space, whether printk also uses relayfs or it has its own implementation??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printk` does not pass data to user space.  It only writes into the kernel ring buffer.  Programs like `dmesg` bring it outside.

See the documentation for `klogctl(2)` (`man 2 klogctl`) for reading the kernel ring buffer.

Comment: ok thanks..can you tell me how dmesg prints it in userspace ??

Comment: @pradeep that's why they invented opensource: http://www.koders.com/c/fid68CBE38F51D05C5CC740D894FBF2FFF130529C52.aspx

Comment: @pradeepchhetri: dmesg gets it from the kernel using `klogctl`. It then prints it to stdout the normal way.